# Как вывести первые 30 записей из БД?

Tags: c#, sql

Удаляю к примеру 2 строки из БД. После этого я хочу вывести первые 30 строк. По моему коду не выходит, так - как он выводит с 1 по 30 Id (получится всего 28 записей)... 
Собственно вопрос: как правильно вывести первые 30 строк? Может можно обойтись без `BETWEEN`?

```
public static void Data_from_DB(int inp_num)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConection())
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Id BETWEEN @start AND @end";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", inp_num + 1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end",   inp_num + 30);

        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read()) { 

                Text.Add((String.Format("{0}", reader["Post_Text"].ToString()))); 
            }

            reader.Close();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM название_таблицы ORDER BY id LIMIT 30` если используется MySQL,

`SELECT TOP(30) * FROM [название_таблицы]` если используется MS SQL,

Ну, и лучше скорее всего указывать точно какие поля вытаскивать.

Comment: а разве не `top(30)`? хотя здесь вроде offset fetch больше подходит

Comment: @ВОРОН, погуглил: top используется только в `СУБД MS SQL Server`. ) так что если используют `MS SQL `то ок) а так в том же `mySQL` аналог `LIMIT`. Хотя раз код на шарпах, то сделаю вывод, что используется `MS SQL `, тогда наверно Ваш вариант правильный.

Comment: а вас не смущает синтаксис запроса? конкретно квадратные скобки вокруг имени таблицы? в mysql это не валидный иснтаксис. Мне что-то подсказывает что здесь именно mssql и используется (тем более раз шарп)

Comment: @ВОРОН, дополнил)

Comment: ну тогда бы и offset fetch упомянули, это вроде аналог limit'а mysql и к тому же этот вариант больше автору подходит, т.к. у него функция получает записи "от" и "до", но работает вроде только с mssql 2012 (может и чуть раньше, не уверен), а для более старых версий можно и через `row_number()` (или как его там) делать

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM [Table] ORDER BY id LIMIT 30`

Comment: а разве не `top(30)`? хотя здесь вроде offset fetch больше подходит

Comment: Я дал первое, что в голову пришло)

Comment: ну вы ошиблись, это сработает только в mysql, а не здесь